# How to make a CLabel in SWT look disabled (Windows)

Tags: java, swt

CLabel.setEnabled(false) apparently does not gray out the label.

Maybe I can use setForeground() to set it to a grey-ish color, but there are still a few questions/concerns:
 a. What color should I use? Will it look as good across platforms.
 b. I will need to save the original color somewhere to make it possible to revert when it's "enabled" again. Also I need to avoid calling setForeground() (from other code) while it's disabled.

Can somebody suggest a better solution? Or at least help answer question a above?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You migh use org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label, its setEnabled method makes component as greyish.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware that CLabel would behave differently in this aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going for the changing color solution, you can try getting a system color (which will normally be platform-dependent) with one of the constants defined in `SWT`, e.g.:

```
Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_TITLE_INACTIVE_FOREGROUND)
```

and the corresponding

```
Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_TITLE_FOREGROUND)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, SWT.COLOR_TITLE_INACTIVE_FOREGROUND doesn't show the correct disabled color in Windows XP for a CLabel. It shows up as a faint gray color and it differs from a disabled Label.